# Does cargo have the ability to detect source changes?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Is there a way to do the equivalent of `cargo run` but only recompile if there are changes to the source files, like `make`?

`.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── input.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── dna.rs
    ├── dynamic.rs
    ├── lib.rs
    └── main.rs`

EDIT: Added `tree` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cargo does this by default.

Create a new project:

```
$ cargo new --bin foo
$ cd foo/
```

Run it:

```
$ cargo run
   Compiling foo v0.0.1 (file:///private/tmp/foo)
     Running `target/foo`
Hello, world!
```

Run it a second time, without changing anything:

```
$ cargo run
     Running `target/foo`
Hello, world!
```

And update the file and run it again:

```
$ touch src/main.rs
$ cargo run
   Compiling foo v0.0.1 (file:///private/tmp/foo)
     Running `target/foo`
Hello, world!
```

Note the lack of `Compiling foo...` in the second run. When the file is modified (here using `touch`), it is recompiled.

For what it's worth, I'm using `cargo 0.0.1-pre-nightly (66849de 2015-03-10) (built 2015-03-11)`.

Comment: Weird, mine is compiling every time. Is the behavior different when you also have internal modules?

Comment: By "*internal modules*", do you mean just other source files, with a corresponding `mod` statement? Or do you mean something else? If the former, then I can say that also does not cause recompilations. Perhaps your editor or something else is falsely updating the modification times?

Comment: Hm, pretty sure VIM isn't touching them. Closed it just to be sure and it's still rebuilding every time. I ran ``stat`` to be sure. I edited my question to include my tree if that helps at all.

Comment: I just confirmed that I see the same behavior with a brand new project created with ``cargo new --bin test``. Every time I run ``cargo run`` it compiles and runs. Rust version is ``rustc 1.0.0-nightly (b0746ff19 2015-03-05) (built 2015-03-06)``

Comment: I'd suggest updating to the newest lately, just to rule out any recent changes to Rust or Cargo. You could also try a `cargo clean` or `git clean`.

Comment: Yep, fixed on nightly.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question you put in the title, "Does cargo have the ability to detect source changes?", the answer is yes, `cargo watch`. It's an extension to `cargo`, so you'll have to download it and compile it before you can use it. https://github.com/passcod/cargo-watch

Of course, from your detailed question it's clear that's not the question you meant to ask, but others who see the title and click the link probably do want the answer to that question.